# PHP / MySQL: Data from MySQL not display in Select Option (dropdown list)

Tags: php, mysql

I created a dropdown list where all the data is populated from a column in a MySQL database table. The problem is, the data is not displayed. I don't know why. Below is my code:

PHP

```
<?php
//getting id from url
$badgeid = $_GET['badgeid'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN roles on users.roles_id = roles.roles_id LEFT JOIN team on users.team_id = team.team_id WHERE badgeid = :badgeid";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':badgeid' => $badgeid));

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $badgeid = $row["badgeid"];;
  $fullname = $row["fullname"];
  $roles_id = $row["roles_id"];
  $roles_name = $row["roles_name"];
  $team_id = $row["team_id"];
  $team_name = $row["team_name"];
}

?>
```

html

```
<tr>
  <td width="20%"><b>Team</b></td>
  <td width="80%">
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="team_name">
    <?php echo "<option value='".$row["team_name"]."'>".$row["team_name"]."</option>"; ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the query through command line?

Comment: $query->fetch will return false after the last record was fetched, so `$row` will contain false after your while loop. You went to the explicit effort of assigning the row values to dedicated variables inside your loop - but then you are not using those afterwards, you are still trying to use $row instead. I am guessing you are expecting at most one record in the result here? Then why use a _loop_ in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change in php at while loop like this,

```
<?php
//getting id from url
$badgeid = $_GET['badgeid'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN roles on users.roles_id = roles.roles_id LEFT JOIN team on users.team_id = team.team_id WHERE badgeid = :badgeid";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':badgeid' => $badgeid));
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row)
{
  $badgeid[] = $row["badgeid"];;
  $fullname[] = $row["fullname"];
  $roles_id[] = $row["roles_id"];
  $roles_name[] = $row["roles_name"];
  $team_id[] = $row["team_id"];
  $team_name[] = $row["team_name"];
}

?>
```

you are directly fetch in while loop , so it skipping first row , so you have not no data in $row . And also use fetchAll() so it fetch all row of table . fetch() only one row.

Comment: `while($row)` – that would just be an endless loop, since $row does never get modified inside the loop.

Comment: @Zar Ni Ko Ko, sorry. your answer wrong. Undefined index from badgeid until team_name

Comment: check my ans again @Radamel Falcao